# Why does `perf stat -a` show clock (Ghz) lower than my cpu is rated?

Tags: perf

Why does `perf stat -a` show a clock speed *three times* lower than my CPU is rated for?

I don't think power management is an issue, because I made sure the test ran for a whole second to allow the cpu frequency to rise to maximum.

```
# time perf stat -a -r 500  mount --make-rprivate /mnt/a

 Performance counter stats for 'system wide' (500 runs):

          6.217301      cpu-clock (msec)          #    3.782 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.63% )
                 6      context-switches          #    0.998 K/sec                    ( +-  1.31% )
                 0      cpu-migrations            #    0.018 K/sec                    ( +- 15.14% )
               122      page-faults               #    0.020 M/sec                    ( +-  0.04% )
         4,719,129      cycles                    #    0.759 GHz                      ( +-  1.93% )
         3,998,374      instructions              #    0.85  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.44% )
           805,593      branches                  #  129.573 M/sec                    ( +-  0.44% )
            22,548      branch-misses             #    2.80% of all branches          ( +-  0.26% )

       0.001644054 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  0.62% )


real    0m1.152s
user    0m0.386s
sys 0m0.824s

# rpm -q perf
perf-4.14.16-300.fc27.x86_64
```

Comment: Note: the CPU does not always run at peak speed. As of right now, my `3.8GHz` CPU is running at `0.56GHz`

Comment: sure, but if you provided an entirely cpu-bound task, you would generally hope to see it crank up to 3.8Ghz.  And I wouldn't expect it to take more than, say, a tenth of a second to do so.  I haven't noticed power management being _that_ intrusive before.

Comment: I struggled a bit in wording the question.  My assumption seeing Ghz as a comment next to cycles, was that it would represent total cycles over the measurement period.  The answer (below) is that `perf` is allowing for programs running on more than on cpu, and it instead shows more of a per-cpu average.  So it's a bit more complex that I expected, in order to better match what people probably intuitively expect when they see Ghz.

Comment: that's actually very odd. I didn't think even just reading `/dev/zero` would do that. Very interesting!

Comment: * `perf` is allowing for programs running on more than _one_ cpu, sorry.  IDGI, what specifically seems very odd to you?  I was trying to work out why a specific metric looked flat wrong to me... with something that black and white, I was already expecting there would be some solid reasons why my assumptions were not justified, and learning these would educate me.

Comment: which indeed turned out to be the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ghz value in `perf stat -a` does not show the cycles per second.  4,719,000 cycles divided by 0.0016 seconds is 2.9Ghz, not 0.76Ghz.

I guess what `perf` shows is an average of the cycles per second *on each cpu core*.  Dividing 2.9Ghz by 0.76Ghz gives 3.8.  This is not quite a whole number of cpus, but it's about right.  I notice it exactly matches the strange "CPUs utilized" figure above.

---

Compare `perf stat` without `-a`:

```
# time perf stat -r 500  mount --make-rprivate /mnt/a

 Performance counter stats for 'mount --make-rprivate /mnt/a' (500 runs):
      1.323450      task-clock (msec)         #    0.812 CPUs utilized            ( +-  0.84% )
             0      context-switches          #    0.008 K/sec                    ( +- 44.54% )
             0      cpu-migrations            #    0.000 K/sec                  
           122      page-faults               #    0.092 M/sec                    ( +-  0.04% )
     2,668,696      cycles                    #    2.016 GHz                      ( +-  0.28% )
     3,090,908      instructions              #    1.16  insn per cycle           ( +-  0.04% )
       611,827      branches                  #  462.297 M/sec                    ( +-  0.03% )
        20,252      branch-misses             #    3.31% of all branches          ( +-  0.09% )

   0.001630517 seconds time elapsed                                          ( +-  0.82% )


real    0m1.089s
user    0m0.378s
sys 0m0.715s
```

Note also, the cycles reported by `perf stat -a` don't exactly represent productive computation.  `perf record -a` followed by `perf report` showed the top hotspot as follows:

```
# perf record -a sh -c "for i in {1..500}; do mount --make-rprivate /mnt/a; done"
...
# perf report
...
  19.40%  swapper          [kernel.kallsyms]           [k] intel_idle
...
```

I.e., although the cpu *frequency* is being lowered on idle cores, the cycles counted by perf appear also appear to include a large number "spent" while the kernel has halted the CPU and entered a cpu idle state.

(Or at least the kernel was *trying* to put the cpu in a low-power idle state.  I don't know if `perf` interrupts the cpu often enough to completely interfere with idling).

Comment: In case `perf` does not document how it computes those figures, it would be interesting to read its source code to find out a definite answer.